# How do I select a json key with hyphens to pass as a prop in React?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-props, react-component, react-state

I am fairly new to React and decided to display some information from a JSON file to get a better understanding of React. I have made a fetch request and am passing the JSON to the state. I am then using this state to pass the data in as props to a custom component. The problem is some of the keys in the JSON are named with - in them. When I try and select the key React throws an error saying the value after the hyphen is undefined. I have tried using jsonObj['key-name'] and have had no luck.

The JSON is structured as so.

```
appearance:{
"eye-color": "Blue",
"gender": "Male",
"hair-color": "Black"
}
```

When passing the data as a property, it is currently being referred to as

```
{appearance.eye-color}
```

Note that I have successfully passed props like

```
{appearance.gender}
```

with no problem.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? If you need more information to understand the issue, that can be shown.

Comment: You need to use square brackets and quotes, like so: `{appearance["eye-color"]}`

Comment: If you can try to avoid hyphens in your props and use camel casing. But if you can't change it you can use bracket notation (as mentioned by Jayce) or rename it in the destructuring. Please have a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-meadow-kjqtw).

Comment: Thanks Jayce444, and AWolf, this fixed the issue. Unfortunately I cannot avoid the naming convention as I am pulling the data from an API out of my control. But this worked perfectly, I appreciate it!